# Summary Widget and Incident Analysis Widget not working after ArcGIS online June 2016 update

Tags: arcgis-online, widget

Has anyone noticed changes to arcgis online widgets with the latest June update?

I am using the Summary Widget and the Incident Analysis Widget (along with other widgets) within an app but these two are no longer fully working with my data since the update.  I have removed my layers then brought them back in and chosen widget settings according to the layers.

I am using the Summary Widget with a filter field selected.  A summary of the whole layer is working but the filter is not working.

I am using the Incident Analysis Widget, this has stopped altogether picking up my data.

I have looked for documentation on these widgets but I have not found anything new.

Any suggestions as to why these tools that previously worked are no longer working or what I might need to do differently?

Comment: Have you asked ESRI?

Comment: I have left questions on ESRI blog/community boards but I am yet to have any communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve done some more testing with the Summary Widget and I’ve found that the bug is not a map service/feature service issue as I had been earlier advised, rather the issue lies with the field name.(DBO.CCTV_Polyline.CCTV_Code_Description)

I tried to create a field alias: Code_Description. This did not change anything.

I added a new field Code_descr and used the field calculator to bring the associated values into this new field … SUCCESS!

I am thinking the problem is the field name length which has somehow had a new constraint added to in this last update.

Answer (score 0):

The change appears to be a new requirement for the layers within these tools to be feature services.

I have been using map services, which previously worked, as a lot of my layers are views rather than tables.